# devise dont work after importing into aptana studio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, aptana

After importing a project into Aptana Studio workspace, I find out that after starting server devise plugin don't work.

```
undefined method `admin_signed_in?'
```

It shows up overtime I want to load any controller where devise functions are used.

I tried.`bundle install`  `gem update rails` also tried to reinstall plugin. Restart server.And so, but nothing seems to work.

On my office PC, project works fine, but I wanted to add something at home, is not working.

**GEM file**

```
gem 'devise'
gem "paperclip", :git => "http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
```

and other built in stuff.

I hope somebody can help.

Edgars

Comment: Did you migrated database?

Comment: @Иван Бишевац  Yes, I done that, still not working :(

Comment: Give some more information about error. Create gist with whole error stack.
What your routes.rb file looks like?

Comment: @Иван Бишевац  For some unknown reasons I was commented out devise_for :admins
     namespace :admins do
     root :to => "controlpanel#index"
end in routes.rb file :D

Comment: For someone else searching for solution, you could accept answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-role, routes.rb should contain line:

```
devise_for :admins
```